# replace repeating PHP code in-place

Tags: php, replace, macros, include, eval

I have many repeating code blocks in my classes that I would like to replace with ... let's call them macros. These blocks can be entire functions, as well as cases within a switch statement, or simple strings and numbers - literally anything, inserted anywhere. Things I have tried:

- include(): will not work to add e.g. functions in classes
- eval(): can't properly debug and seems generally a poor idea
- proper inheritance: i would like to get around a rewrite this time
- define: does not seem to behave like in c/c++, or I am doing something wrong

Please let me know if it is possible to get macro-like functionality in PHP. I have googled SO and found a handful of quite old threads that said this was not supported, however things might have changed in the last few years, so please let me know. Regards

Comment: Have you looked into traits?

Comment: Traits look promising

Comment: Thank you both. Indeed, I managed to use traits to code around my issue, and while it's not exactly what I wanted to use, it's flexible and easy enough to work with. cheers